# Node Canvas trying to load custom font

Tags: javascript, node.js, fonts

I am attempting to get the font "Gotham Black" into my code for node canvas. While I have the .otf file inside the project and the correct path towards it, normal Gotham is displayed even though the file is that of Gotham Black.

```
const fontPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Gotham-Black.otf');

registerFont(fontPath, { family: 'Gotham', style: 'bold' });
context.font = 'bold 90px "Gotham"';
```

I have already tried changing the font family name to Gotham Black but that just makes no text appear. The font is registered before the creation of the canvas.

Comment: Give it a name that isn't already used by the system.

Comment: If i change the name no text show at all.

Comment: Then that's information you can work with. Don't use names that are already allocated to get the "real" result. The reason you're getting regular Gotham is because you already have that installed. So, some checks: does the font exist on the `fontPath` location? And don't go checking manually, ask Node by using `fs.existsSync(fontPath)` to see if it sees a file there or not.

Comment: And of course remember [the docs](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/#registerfont): "To use a font file that is not installed as a system font, use `registerFont()` to register the font with Canvas. *This must be done before the Canvas is created*." so did you remember to do this before creating your canvas instance?

Comment: yes, I said that at the bottom of the post. It has been registered before. The file path is correct and the file is the .otf file with the correct font I want.

Comment: Then you'll want to show a proper [mcve], because right now you're not showing enough code for someone to reproduce the problem you're having. Also, since node-canvas is open source with a pubilc issue tracker: did you also ask there? (since their issue tracker is _the_ authority when it comes to node-canvas. If their docs don't cover what you need to do, or following their docs doesn't work for you, they want to know about that)